# Irregular bootstrap3 grid, one column out of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm seeing some crazy layouts sometimes. One of them is layout where we have boostrap container that has max width, let's say 1120px.

One of columns has 50% width of container, and the second has 50% width, not container but browser.

I've attached 2 screens to clarify my question - and the question is: does anybody has claver solution, that is responsive and will not break things during resisizing ?
So, 2 columns will not collapse ?

I will not provide html / css code, as i have no idea, how to code this right and without javascript.

If any of You have any ideas, i'm saying "thanks for a tip :)"

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to post your code...

Comment: what code you want ?

Comment: if i don't know how to code this right, how can i provide you a code ? I'm asking for clues how to code this right , or you want this :

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @Johannes if this question was too hard for you, or you cannot understend this very easy layout and the problem, why you are asking for code that i'm not able to give, as i don't know what code give you ?

Comment: @user3573535 enough code to reproduce the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: @ZeroRequiem, Pavel was able to reproduce, help and give me solution that works for me.
I don't need anything more here, as Pavel understund this fast and very well.

Comment: @user3573535 If you ask a question here about a coding problem, you are expected to post the relevant code that helps to show and reproduce the problem. In this case, that would be mainly HTML including the Bootstrap classes. I don't understand why you get all upset by my comment (which you will find in similar form under thousands of other questions by hundreds of other people), to an extent where you apparently even dig out two old, accepted and quite good rated answers of mine and downvote them?

Comment: @Johannes it's simple: if you think, you cannot do anything clever,or helpful, i think best to not do anything. Yor idea was to downvote after 2 minutes when this post appears, and this may looks like you didn't even try to understand the problem. I think, in this case sometimes best to act as human being and not act people like monkeys. besides, i dont agree with you with your some posts, and what's more, you may feel like me sometimes. ... Be human bro....

Comment: I didn't downvote - I wrote a comment. What do you not agree with about that comment?

Comment: @Johannes: "mainly HTML including the Bootstrap classes" - sorry bro, this is your clever answer ? Even if hurt you beacuse you dont know "col-sm-6" i've done2 screenshots to help understand this problem. Pavel figured this in 6 mins...So i think it was not too hard to undersarstand? or maybe you didn't read all the topic ? In this case best to do nothing i guess. bye.

Comment: @Johannes , i dont blame you - thank you for response, but as you see we are loosking time on tings that are resolved. Thank you Pavel, and you too for making this community alive. Cheers.

Comment: @Johannes i don't agree with everything. I wrote that i have no code to show as i don't know how to write. Now you are saiyng that i didn't provide boostrap classes ? Relly ? Maybe you are right, but surely you are not the person that is asking for Boostrap as you know them very well. So this makes no sense.

Comment: If you don't know how to write HTML code, how did you ever get the result you presented as images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `width: calc()` to calculate any width you want.

quick example

https://codepen.io/kupas/pen/Yepadv

PS: for smaller screen use mediaqueries